# Why can't I export my rigs?

Tags: objects, rigging, export

I made a series of characters for a game I am working on in Unreal, but when I export them, they don't seem to have their rig anymore. I imported the finished models to find they don't have rigs on them despite how they were exported. Is this a normal thing that happens in Blender, where I can't load in or export rigs? Or is my issue with Unreal, which isn't reading any rigs off the models?

Also, I am not sure if this has anything to do with this issue, but I exported my models in .obj format.

Comment: Have you already seen videos like this 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h47e62Mx-ok
and it didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

From the wikipedia [wavefront obj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) page -

> The OBJ file format is a simple data-format that represents 3D geometry alone — namely, the position of each vertex, the UV position of each texture coordinate vertex, vertex normals, and the faces that make each polygon defined as a list of vertices, and texture vertices

If you look in the unreal docs under [Managing content](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Content/index.html) they only mention fbx as a format for importing static or skeletal meshes. Blender includes an fbx import/export addon, if you don't see the fbx export option then you will need to enable the addon.

There is also an addon available that eases the blender -> UE process, available on [github](https://github.com/meta-androcto/blenderpython/blob/master/scripts/addons_extern/ue_tools_v1-2-4.py).